# Not getting the correct answer

Tags: c

What is wrong with this code? It is giving me ridiculously high values for Celsius.`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int temp (int fahr, int celsius) 
{
 celsius = 5*(fahr-32)/9
}
int main() {

int fahr, celsius;
printf ("Enter fahrenheit value here: ");
scanf("%d", &fahr);
printf ("The Celsius value is: %d ",celsius);
return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: The code above shouldn't even compile much less return correct values.

Comment: Your function `temp` is declared to return an `int`, but it doesn’t return anything. That doesn’t matter yet, though, because you didn’t call it, either. Turn on all warnings when compiling and pay attention to them.

Comment: planning on calling the `temp` function? And you'll have to return the value from that function,, or make it a `void` and pass in a pointer to `celsius`

Comment: Also, you might want to make the `int` data types to `float` since you are dividing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int temp(int fahr) 
{
  return 5*(fahr-32)/9;
}

int main() {
  int fahr, celsius;
  printf ("Enter fahrenheit value here: ");
  scanf("%d", &fahr);
  celsius = temp(fahr);
  printf ("The Celsius value is: %d ", celsius);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Everyone’s comments and criticisms are correct. My answer is to show things working, but no more. You should read what others have written and explore your work more carefully.

Comment: Hmmm, lower f for [Daniel Fahrenheit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Gabriel_Fahrenheit) yet upper C for [Anders Celsius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Celsius).  Some guys get [no respect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iwu-6GxBHN4). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're never calling `temp()`, so you're just printing whatever random garbage is at the memory location of the unitialised `celsius` variable.

Also a bunch of other things wrong with the code:

- Missing semicolon in the definition of `temp()`.
- You should be `return`ing the result value from `temp()`, not assigning it to a parameter.

Comment: Even if OP calls temp, local variable celsius is never modified by the function, so still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're passing parameters per value, not per reference, I'd modify your code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int fahr;
printf ("Enter fahrenheit value here: ");
scanf("%d", &fahr);
printf ("The Celsius value is: %d ",temp(fahr));
return 0;
}

int temp (int fahr) 
{
   int celsius = 5*(fahr-32)/9
   return celsius;
}
```

Or use params per reference.

Answer (score 0):

Most simplified version using a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int temp(int fahr)
{
    return 5*(fahr-32)/9;
}

int main() {
    int fahr;
    printf ("Enter fahrenheit value here: ");
    scanf("%d", &fahr);
    printf ("The Celsius value is: %d ", temp(fahr));
}
```

No function:

```
int main() {
    int fahr;
    printf ("Enter fahrenheit value here: ");
    scanf("%d", &fahr);
    printf ("The Celsius value is: %d ", (5*(fahr-32)/9));
}
```